# How to add this combinations? PLEASE HELP

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to solve this?

$\dbinom{1000}{50} + \dbinom{999}{49} + \dbinom{998}{48} + \dbinom{997}{47} +\cdots+ \dbinom{951}{1} + \dbinom{950}{0}$

I was solving some problem which goes like this
[image: here]

Not knowing any other better method (if exists), I thought of adding the coefficients of **x^50** from each term!

And reached the step as depicted above.

Comment: This is a diagonal on Pascal's triangle and there are nice identities. Have a search, see if you can find it. You might want to look up triangular numbers. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413046/pascals-triangle-sum-of-nth-diagonal-row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

The expression is same as 
$$\binom {1000}{950}+\binom {999}{950}+\binom {998}{950}\cdots +\binom {950}{950}$$

And now use the [Hockey stick identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity)  to get the answer as $\binom {1001}{951}$

Answer (score 3):

Using [Pascal's Identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Pascal%27s_Identity),

$$\binom  nk=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}k$$

$$\iff\binom  nk-\binom{n-1}k=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

$$\implies\binom{950+k}k-\binom{950+k-1}k=\binom{950+k-1}{k-1}$$

Set $k=1,\cdots,50$ and add

Answer (score 3):

From Pascal's triangle, the idea behind is this

[image]